# Pass my credentials from a ssh session to another ssh session

Tags: ssh

I want to ssh from A to B, using a particular private key that I have in A. Then I want to ssh from B to C using the same credentials that I used to ssh into B.

Is it possible to "pass" the credentials from a ssh session to another ssh session started inside the first session?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes.

What you are looking for is known as [ssh-agent forwarding](http://www.unixwiz.net/techtips/ssh-agent-forwarding.html). Once you learn to use `ssh-agent` to load up your unlocked keys and make them available to the `ssh-client`, it is possible for the clients to pass this data down the chain of connections so that future ssh clients can talk to the original agent.

Among other things, you will need to setup `ForwardAgent yes` in your [ssh configs](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12101/pass-my-credentials-from-a-ssh-session-to-another-ssh-session/12173#12173) for the various machines that should be allowed these privaleges. You should be aware that this introduces several new layers of security issues. You are playing with fire. Don't say we didn't warn you!

Comment: I added some more detail on configuring SSH as a second answer.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is in addition to [what Caleb wrote](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12101/pass-my-credentials-from-a-ssh-session-to-another-ssh-session/12105#12105).  You should be careful enabling SSH Agent forwarding to untrusted hosts.  What I do is list specific hosts in my `~/.ssh/config` file as such:

```
ForwardX11 yes

Host trusted-server
    ForwardAgent yes
    Compression yes

Host trusted-desktop
    ForwardAgent yes
    ForwardX11Trusted yes
```

This enables X11 forwarding for everyone, but OpenSSH filters out SECURITY commands.  Compression is enabled to the server, Trusted X11 (without filtering) is enabled to the desktop and SSH Agent is enabled when connecting to either.